# Is it possible to create multiple sessions of a VM instance in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, multiple-instances, docker-image, google-container-registry

When systems are used remotely, it is possible for multiple users to use the system remotely via SSH. The only condition being the system should be powered on and should be connected to a active Internet connect. Similarly, I want to create a VM instance in google cloud which will be running at all times. This VM instance will be deployed with a docker image from Container registry that needs 3 arguments. Is it possible to create different sessions of this VM instance? The only difference between the sessions will be arguments to the docker image. All these sessions will have to run parallelly.

Comment: Are you trying to run multiple containers of some docker image on a VM, one container for each user, and each one of these users will ssh into the VM and use his container? Please add more details on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Your use case isn't clear. Why do you need to have the same VM?

Comment: Could you please add more details on your question ?   My understanding is similar to what Atef described,  but could you please add more details